# When does trivial topology implies continuous functions are constant functions?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, separation-axioms

I found this question: [$f$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791995/topology-f-is-continuous-iff-f-is-constant)

But I wondered whether all the assumptions are necessary. I think we can state the following claim as well:

> Let $f:X_1\rightarrow X_2$ be a continuous map, where $X_1$ has the trivial topology and $X_2$ has a $T_1$ topology. Then $f$ is constant.

My argument is simple:

Assume towards contradicition that $y_1,y_2\in X_2$ are distinct points attained by $f$. Then $f^{-1}[\{y_1\}]$ is closed and not $X_1$, which is a contradicition. Hence $f$ must be constant.

My question is whether I can reduce the requirement on $X_2$ to simply be a $T_0$ space? I think such an argument would be true for $y_1,y_2\in X_2$ attained by $f$ such that we have a neighbourhood $U\subset X_2$ such that $y_1\in U$ and $y_2\in U$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is enough if $X_2$ is a $T_0$ space.

Then if a function is *not* constant, i.e its image contains at least $2$ distinct points, there is an open set $U$ containing exactly one of these points.

The preimage of $U$ cannot be an element of $\{\varnothing, X_1\}$ so the function is *not* continuous.

Comment: And trivially we cannot weaken $T_0$: we could  have the trivial topology on the codomain as well, and **any** function is continuous....