# Continuous functions on trivial topologies are constant?

Tags: general-topology

I am reading Singer/Thorpe Lecture Notes on Elementary Topology and Geometry and at the start of Section 2.2 it is stated, "If *S* is a topological space in which the only open sets are the empty set and *S*, then one sees easily that the only continuous real-valued functions on *S* are the constant functions."

I have been stuck at this section for a couple of days, as I am having trouble with the above statement. If I consider an arbitrary set *S* with more than one element and the trivial topology on *S*, then the identity mapping from *S* to itself should be both continuous (preimage of the empty set and *S* itself are the empty set and *S*, so both are open) and non-constant (as *S* has more than one element, so more than one element is mapped to).

The answers to this question on stack exchange: [When does trivial topology implies continuous functions are constant functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3475832/when-does-trivial-topology-implies-continuous-functions-are-constant-functions) seem to also imply that there would be additional requirements necessary in order to make the original statement true.

I'm guessing there is a logical error in my counterexample and that I am misunderstanding the text, but I am having trouble in figuring it out myself. Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: Their assertion is about _real_ -valued functions, not $S$-valued!

Comment: More generally, if $T$ is a topological space in which all singleton sets are closed, then the only continuous functions from $S$ to $T$ are constant functions. (One can even get away with $T$ being a $T_0$ space, as the answer to the linked question shows.)

Comment: @GregMartin Looking at the linked answer,  this criteria is equivalent to being $T_0$, correct?  That all continuous functions from nontrivial discrete spaces are constant?

Comment: I think you mean trivial rather than discrete. I don't think the linked answer or comment establishes equivalence, and I don't know if they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f: S \to \Bbb R$ is continuous (where $\Bbb R$ has its standard topology; this is what's meant by a "continuous real-valued function") and $f$ is **not** constant, then $f$ assumes at least two distinct values, say $f(s_0) \neq f(s_1)$, say WLOG $f(s_0) < f(s_1)$. Then $U = (\leftarrow, f(s_1))$ is open in $\Bbb R$ (it's an open segment so open in the order topology), $f(s_1) \notin U$ so $s_1 \notin f^{-1}[U]$, and $f(s_0) \in U$ so $s_0 \in f^{-1}[U]$.

As $f$ is assumed to be continuous, $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $S$ while $\emptyset \neq f^{-1}[U] \neq S$, which contradicts the fact that $S$ has the trivial topology. So $f$ was constant QED.

We could also have used the closed set $\{f(s_0)\}$ as well for a similar reasoning with closed sets etc. In the linked question they use only that we could take this closed singleton set as $\Bbb R$ is a $T_1$ space. So it's essentially that same argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, that fully explained what I was not understanding - the real valued part of the statement! I would upvote your answer, but as a new member do not yet have the reputation to do so.

Comment: @user3574703 You're welcome. And accepting it is enough..

Comment: What does $\leftarrow$ in $U = (\leftarrow, f(s_1))$ mean?

Comment: @md2perpe the open set of all points in $\Bbb R$ that are $< f(s_1)$. This is a reasonably standard notation.

Comment: The same as $(-\infty, f(s_1))$? I've never seen your notation before.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for that notation? I'd like to learn more about it.

Comment: @md2perpe my old high school books. Among others. Or any book on order theory.

Comment: Any resource online?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Let $c\in f(S)$ and $\epsilon>0.$ Then $I=(c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$ is open so since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(I)\subseteq S$ is open. But there are only two open sets in $S$: the empty set and the whole of $S$. And since $c\in f(S),$ $f^{-1}(I)$ cannot be empty but must be all of $S$. Thus, $f(S) \subseteq (c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon).$ Since this is valid for all $\epsilon>0$ this implies that $f(S)=\{c\},$ i.e. $f$ is constant.